# How to get the exact response Status Code while calling an API using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written a service to call another API service. But at times, when I call the service I get an error message. One such error is "Unbound Parameters found", but the status code what I get is 200. So, I hope 200 is not the correct status code here for this kind of error output.

How to get the correct status code for this case?

The method currently I use to get the Status code is response.statusCode

```
function apiCall(url, protocol) {
function externalApi(url, callback) {
    try {
        var https = $.require(protocol);
        var request = https.request(url, function (response) {
            var str = '';
            var statusCode = response.statusCode;
            var headers = response.headers;
            response.on('data', function (data) {
                str += data;
            });
            response.on('end', function () {
                console.log("Data is " + str);
                console.log("Status Code is " + statusCode);
                console.log("Header is " + JSON.stringify(headers));
                callback(str, statusCode);
            });
        });

        request.on('error', function (e) {
            console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
            console.log('Problem with request: ' + e);
        });
        request.end();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("the error is" + err);
        var errCode = err.statusCode;
        callback(err, 999);
    }
}
var status = function (data, statusCode) {
    var callStatus = {};
    if (statusCode == 200) {
        callStatus.retrievedData = data;
        callStatus.statusCode = statusCode;
        callStatus.MESSAGE = "API successfully called";
    } else if (statusCode == 999) {
        callStatus.MESSAGE = "API call failed";
        callStatus.errorDetails = data;
        callStatus.errorDescription = "Error generated from Catch Block";
    } else {
        callStatus.details = data;
        callStatus.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
    console.log(callStatus);
};
externalApi(url, status);
}
```

What i get is the error message, but status code as 200. But what would I need is error message with the exact error status code.

Comment: Talk to third-party API support that they are sending 200 with response text - "Unbound Parameters found", maybe they are also not aware of this situation

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Does 200 here indicate that the API is successfully called? Or it is the third party API that is not sending the correct response Status Code?

Comment: Yes, 200 response indicates it is successfully called and you received the message as well.